# How to collapse very correlated words?

Tags: r, nlp

I selected the most important words in a text using tf-idf method. The problem is that this method gives me a lot of words that are very correlated and represent the same context, which does not bring me new information. I want to maximize, therefore, the number of 'important' words that are not related between each other.

I came to the following solution:

```
text <- read_csv('texto.csv')

tfidf <- text %>%
unnest_tokens(word, `Texto do Comentário`) %>%
count(word, document) %>%
bind_tf_idf(word, document, n) %>%
top_n(10, tf_idf)

# Now, I use the words generated by tf-idf to find out how these words correlate with the others on the corpus.

correlations <- text %>%
unnest_tokens(word, `Texto do Comentário`) %>%
pairwise_cor(word, document) %>%
filter(item2 %in% tfidf$word)
```

So, this is the furthest I could get. Now I would like to cluster the very correlated words (correlation > .7) and collapse them into just one word that are the most correlated between them. I am not sure what the best method is (PCA? Factor Analysis?) and could find little help on the Internet regarding this task.

Comment: Have you taken a look at approaches to "topic modeling"?

Comment: I suggest to investigate word2vec methods and then do clustering of word vectors and select the term which is the closest to the centroid of your cluster to make it a preferred term.